# 403 Exception when attempting to build DataFrame from parquet file in S3 locally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm building a Spark application and trying to run it locally before launching it on EMR or in a container. I can get a DataFrame to work just fine when the parquet file itself is local, but it refuses to read the parquet file if it's in S3. I have attempted to set all the variables I can think of that are suggested when reading in from S3a, here's how I'm creating my Spark session:

```scala
package util

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.io.Source

object SparkSessionFactory {

  def generateSession(sessionLocation: String): SparkSession = {
    val session = {
      sessionLocation match {
        case "local" =>
          SparkSession.builder().appName("LocalS3SparkProfiler").master("yarn").master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
            .config("fs.s3a.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
            .config("fs.s3a.serverSideEncryptionAlgorithm", "aws:kms")
            .getOrCreate()
      }
    }
    setHadoopConfigs(session, sessionLocation)
    session
  }

  private def setHadoopConfigs(session:SparkSession, sessionLocation:String) = {
    session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
    sessionLocation match {
      case "local"=> {
        val userHome = System.getProperty("user.home")
        val aWSCredentialsLines = Source.fromFile(s"$userHome/.aws/credentials").getLines.toList

        val key = aWSCredentialsLines(1).substring(aWSCredentialsLines(1).lastIndexOf(" ")).trim
        val secret = aWSCredentialsLines(2).substring(aWSCredentialsLines(2).lastIndexOf(" ")).trim
        val s3Token = aWSCredentialsLines(3).substring(aWSCredentialsLines(3).lastIndexOf(" ")).trim

        session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", key)
        session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret)
        session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.session.token", s3Token)
        session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then when I attempt to read the data frame I call

```scala
val spark = SparkSessionFactory.generateSession("local")
val df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://my-bucket/thepath/myparquetfile")
```

And the error thrown is as  follows:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service:
>   Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
>   366CFE11F21144F3; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   eW4C6PQZ4uSJOPmYKoZ8qCwmK4PwL6eFPwef9e1KLA3kL2LsiCMctZ+ZLYVplZh927iNiSro7ko=),
>   S3 Extended Request ID:
>   eW4C6PQZ4uSJOPmYKoZ8qCwmK4PwL6eFPwef9e1KLA3kL2LsiCMctZ+ZLYVplZh927iNiSro7ko=
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4330)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4277)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1265)

Everything I've read suggests the credentials I need are the ones I'm providing. I've checked the `key` , `secret` , and `s3Token` values, and they look correct, as I use those credentials in another project that uses the normal AWS SDK with no problem.

Any idea on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging AWS Auth failures is hard as neither AWS nor anyone implementing clients want to log secrets to the console. "403" is generally as useless as "400" for debugging

1. Have a look at [Troubleshooting S3A](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#Authentication_Failure)
2. As well as direct auth problems, you get an auth failure if a file is SSE-KMS encrypted with an AWS KMS key do which your account doesn't have access. the error message doesn't call this out specifically.
3. Try the AWS cli with the same creds to see they work. If they let you see the data then it's inevitably some spark/s3a config issue.
4. Download a recent version of Hadoop (ideally 3.2), install it and configure it's core-site.xml with the options. Then use [Cloudstore storediag](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/) to let it do a structured debug of the logon process. If that doesn't work, spark isn't going to either.